# vscode debug setting in launch.json with custom executable inside pipenv

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hello I'm working with pipenv which have a differetn path for every developer, but I want to have the same launch setting for all. The problem is that the program is not the python is a custom executable with is under the virtual environment bin folder. 
Here is my current `launch.json`

```
{
     "name": "Python: TEST",
     "type": "python",
     "request": "launch",
     "stopOnEntry": false,
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
     "program": "${env:HOME}/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-PbRe8Lzd/bin/<program>",
     "args": [
              ...
             ],
     "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
}
```

And for me works OK becaouse my  is under "venv-PbRe8Lzd/bin/" but for the other developers that have different venv folder no. Any Idea on how to do this generic for all?

Answer (score 5):

I think better not to sync .vscode folder at all. But anyway it's possible to put interpreter path into another file ".vscode/settings.json".

1. Delete "program" from launch.json.
2. Install the Python extension for Visual Studio Code https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python (probably it's already installed)
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+P
4. Search "Python: Select Interpreter"
5. Select pipenv interpreter path

or

3. Create/modify file ".vscode/settings.json"

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${env:HOME}/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-PbRe8Lzd/bin/python"
}
```

Comment: error: "Invalid message: either "program", "module", or "code" must be specified.

otherwise very useful!
"program": "${file}", //works for me